# Can you create a nested array by combining two ranges?

Tags: ruby

I am currently creating a Chess game, and I'm setting up an array for each chess piece which contains their legal move set. For example, a bishop can only move diagonally so the move set would need to be the following to move in a left upwards diagonal.

```
[[-1, -1], [-2, -2] ...repeated... [-7, -7], [-8, -8]]
```

Rather than having long lines of code for each direction, is there a way I can created a nested array with two range?

Eg:

```
([-1, -1])..([-8, -8])
```

Comment: Have you considered something like the following? `def bishop_moves(row, col); diff = col - row; (0..7).each_with_object([]) do |r,a|; next if r == row; c = r + diff; a << [r,c] if (0..7).cover?(c); c = 2*col - c; a << [r,c] if (0..7).cover?(c); end; end`, where the arguments of the method are the bishop's current location?...

Comment: ...Then, for example, `bishop_moves(2,4) #=>[[0, 2], [0, 6], [1, 3], [1, 5], [3, 5], [3, 3], [4, 6], [4, 2], [5, 7], [5, 1], [6, 0]]` and `bishop_moves(4,2) #=> [[0, 6], [1, 5], [2, 0], [2, 4], [3, 1], [3, 3], [5, 3], [5, 1], [6, 4], [6, 0], [7, 5]]`. – Cary Swoveland 6 hours ago    Delete

Answer (score 6):

[`Enumerable#zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) combines two enumerations.

```
(-8..-1).zip(-8..-1).reverse
  # => [[-1, -1], [-2, -2], [-3, -3], [-4, -4], [-5, -5], [-6, -6], [-7, -7], [-8, -8]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe OT, but you can accomplish the same result with different approach, which could help with other chess pieces.

For example:

```
(1..8).map { |n| [-n, -n] }
#=> [[-1, -1], [-2, -2], [-3, -3], [-4, -4], [-5, -5], [-6, -6], [-7, -7], [-8, -8]]
```

Or also:

```
8.times.map { |n| [-n-1, -n-1] }
#=> [[-1, -1], [-2, -2], [-3, -3], [-4, -4], [-5, -5], [-6, -6], [-7, -7], [-8, -8]]
```